# How can I programmatically rotate all the pages in a PDF using native macOS tools?

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript

Given a file path, I need to rotate all the pages in a PDF at that file path using nothing that isn't included with macOS. The wrapper for this will be AppleScript, so I also have access to the command line and therefore all of the scripting languages installed by default with macOS, but nothing that would require `brew` or, for example, Python's `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I used.

- Automator to separate the PDF into individual pages in a new folder at the same level as the original PDF
- Some AppleScript to rotate a single page PDF using Image Events
- A second Automator workflow to stitch the separate PDFs back together again
- An AppleScript that controls everything, using `do shell script` to `open` each of the Automator workflows as needed.

Answer (score 5):

PDF page rotation can be performed using standard Preview application.

Just after opening a PDF document, hit 1 or 2 times tab key (depending of your Preview version) in order to select all pages on side bar with 'cmd a'.
Then hit 'cmd R' (or L) to rotate 90% right (or left) all selected pages and finally hit 'cmd w' to close the window.
Preview will ask to save changes by default, then only hit enter key to save.

You can simulate all these keys in Applescript using Keystroke instruction from System Events.

To use this subroutine for many PDF files, you have 2 solutions, still in Applescript:

1) Select a folder and loop through all PDF files of that folder to apply this sub-routine.

2) Select your files in "Finder" and your script will take directly all Finder selected files to apply same sub-routine.

Such GUI scripting is not perfect, but Preview is not scriptable ...unfortunately )-:

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge **macOS** does not have *any one native command line Unix executable* that can *rotate all pages* in a **PDF** (while keeping text based ones text based). `sip` can rotate a single page **PDF** however the resulting **PDF** is an *encapsulated image*, not *text* if it was text base to begin with. Also, not sure if there is a way with just *plain* **AppleScript**, other then via **UI Scripting** the *default* **Preview** application, without going to **AppleScriptObjC** (**Cocoa-AppleScript**) and or **Python**, etc.

Using *third-party command line utilities* is probably the easiest, but you said it has to be done only using what's *a default part of* **macOS**. So, I'll offer an **AppleScript** solution that uses **UI Scripting** the *default* **Preview** application, that can be used in the event there isn't another way with **AppleScriptObjC** or without *third-party utilities*, etc.

This solution, as offered (and coded), assumes that **Preview** is the *default* application for **PDF** documents and uses it to *rotate* all the pages in the **PDF** document. It is also setup as an **Automator** *workflow*. (Although there are other ways to incorporate the AppleScript *code* shown below.)

First, in **Finder**, make a copy of the target **PDF** documents and work with those.

In **Automator**, create a new *workflow* document, adding the following *actions*:

- **Get Specified Finder Items**

  - *Add* the copied target **PDF** document to this *action*.
- **Run AppleScript Script**

  - *Replace* the *default code* with the *code* below:

**AppleScript *code*:**

```
on run {input}
    set thisLong to 0.25 -- # The value of 'thisLong' is decimal seconds delay between keystrokes, adjust as necessary.
    set theRotation to "r" -- # Valid values are 'l' or 'r' for Rotate Left or Rotate Right.
    set theViewMenuCheckedList to {}
    set theMenuItemChecked to missing value
    repeat with thisItem in input
        tell application "Finder" to open file thisItem -- # By default, in this use case, the PDF file will open in Preview.
        delay 1 --  # Adjust as necessary. This is the only 'delay' not defined by the value of 'thisLong'.
        tell application "System Events"
            perform action "AXRaise" of window 1 of application process "Preview" -- # Just to make sure 'window 1' is front-most.
            delay thisLong
            --  # Ascertain which of the first six 'View' menu items is checked.
            set theViewMenuCheckedList to (value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu items 1 thru 6 of menu 1 of menu bar item 5 of menu bar 1 of application process "Preview")
            repeat with i from 1 to 6
                if item i in theViewMenuCheckedList is not missing value then
                    set theMenuItemChecked to i as integer
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
            --  # Process keystrokes based on which 'View' menu item is checked.
            --  # This is being done so the subsequent keystroke ⌘A 'Select All' 
            --  # occurs on the 'Thumbnails', not the body of the document.
            if theMenuItemChecked is not 2 then
                repeat with thisKey in {"2", "1", "2"}
                    keystroke thisKey using {option down, command down}
                    delay thisLong
                end repeat
            else
                repeat with thisKey in {"1", "2"}
                    keystroke thisKey using {option down, command down}
                    delay thisLong
                end repeat
            end if
            repeat with thisKey in {"a", theRotation as text, "s"} -- # {Select All, Rotate Direction, Save}
                keystroke thisKey using {command down}
                delay thisLong
            end repeat
            keystroke theMenuItemChecked as text using {option down, command down} -- # Resets the 'View' menu to the original view.
            delay thisLong
            keystroke "w" using {command down} -- # Close Window.
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

**Notes:**

- As this *script* uses **UI Scripting**, when run from **Automator** (or **Script Editor**), the running app must be added to **System Preferences** > **Security** & **Privacy** > **Accessibility** in order to *run* properly. Saved as an *application*, the saved application would need to be added.
- Also with **UI Scripting**, the value of the `delay` *commands* may need to be changed for use on your system (and or additional `delay` *commands* added as appropriate, although in the case additional `delay` *commands* should not be needed). It should go without saying however test this on a set of a few document first to make sure the value set for `thisLong` works on your system. On my system this worked as coded.
- When using **UI Scripting** in this manner, once the task has started, one must leave the system alone and let it finish processing the files. Trying to multi-task will only set focus away from the task at hand and cause it to fail.
- If you need to rotate more then one time, add additional `theRotation as text,` to:

  ```
    repeat with thisKey in {"a", theRotation as text, "s"} -- # {Select All, Rotate Direction, Save}
  ```

  Example:

  ```
    repeat with thisKey in {"a", theRotation as text, theRotation as text, "s"}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method of the **PDFPage** from a **Cocoa-AppleScript**.

Look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument?language=objc and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfpage?language=objc

---

Here's the script:

```
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

set thisPath to POSIX path of (choose file of type {"pdf"} with prompt "Choose a PDF") --  a POSIX path, not an alias or an HFSPath
set thisDoc to current application's PDFDocument's alloc()'s initWithURL:(current application's NSURL's fileURLWithPath:thisPath)

set pCount to thisDoc's pageCount()
repeat with i from 0 to (pCount - 1)
    ((thisDoc's pageAtIndex:i)'s setRotation:90) -- rotate to 90,  the rotation must be a positive or negative multiple of 90: (0, 90, 180, 270 or -90 -180 -270)
end repeat
thisDoc's writeToFile:thisPath -- save --
```

---

Note: this script will work properly, if the rotation of the page is **0** (no rotation), otherwise you must get the rotation of the page and do a calculation.

---

Here's an example to rotate the pages to right or left:

```
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

set thisPath to POSIX path of (choose file of type {"pdf"} with prompt "Choose a PDF") --  a POSIX path, not an alias or an HFSPath
my rotatePages(thisPath, 90) -- rotate right , use -90 to rotate left

on rotatePages(thisPath, r)
    set thisDoc to current application's PDFDocument's alloc()'s initWithURL:(current application's NSURL's fileURLWithPath:thisPath)
    set pCount to thisDoc's pageCount()
    repeat with i from 0 to (pCount - 1)
        set thisPage to (thisDoc's pageAtIndex:i)
        (thisPage's setRotation:((thisPage's |rotation|()) + r)) -- add 90 to the current rotation, note: at 360, the value of the rotation will be set to 0, not to 360
    end repeat
    thisDoc's writeToFile:thisPath -- save --
end rotatePages
```

Comment: I figured you'd be along with a Cocoa-AppleScript solution. :) It would be nice if you would include an example of how to do "_otherwise you must get the rotation of the page and do a calculation_" from your note at the bottom of your answer.

Comment: I added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Swift as a scripting language. The Shortcuts.app includes an option to use Swift in its "Run Shell Script" action.

The following script will rotate all pages of PDFs supplied as filenames in its arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

// ROTATE PAGES: Rotate all pages of selected PDFs by 90˚

import Foundation
import Quartz

func newURL(filepath: String, newbit: String) -> String {
    var newname = filepath
    while (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: newname)) {
    newname = (newname as NSString).deletingPathExtension
// Could be improved with incremental number added to filename
    newname += newbit
    }
return newname
}

func rotatePage(filepath: String) -> Void {
    let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
    let newFilepath = newURL(filepath: filepath, newbit: " +90.pdf")
    if let pdfDoc = PDFDocument.init(url: pdfURL) {
        let pages = pdfDoc.pageCount
        for p in (0...pages) {
            let page = pdfDoc.page(at: p)
            var newRotation: Int = 90
            if let existingRotation = page?.rotation {
                newRotation = (existingRotation + 90) as Int
            }
            page?.rotation = newRotation
    }
        pdfDoc.write(toFile: newFilepath)
    }
    
    return
}

// "main"
if CommandLine.argc > 1 {
    for (index, args) in CommandLine.arguments.enumerated() {
        if index > 0 {
            rotatePage(filepath: args)
            
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MacOS comes with python, and you can use it in Automator *(Run shell script - set to python, pass inputs as arguments)* to create a service that will work on PDFs in the Finder.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
import sys
import os
from Quartz import PDFDocument
from CoreFoundation import NSURL

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
        shortName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filename)
        pdfDoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
        pages = pdfDoc.pageCount()
        for p in range(0, pages):
            page = pdfDoc.pageAtIndex_(p)
            existingRotation = page.rotation()
            newRotation = existingRotation + 90
            page.setRotation_(newRotation)

        pdfDoc.writeToFile_(filename)
```

You can find a whole load of similar scripts and Automator workflows at [this GitHub site](https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite)